# Setting a global variable and accessing it in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, global-variables

I'm having problems creating a global variable and resetting it through jquery. here is my code

```
var x = 1;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").click(function () {
        if(x === 1) {
            alert("test1");
            var x = 2;
        } else if(x === 2) {
            alert("test2");
            var x = 3;
        } else {
            alert("test 3");
        }
    });
});
```

I want to be able to click the same button three times and have all the tests appear, but instead it goes straight to the last option `"test 3"`. I apologize if this is a silly question, but I'm a bit new to jquery and javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `var` from the variable assignment inside the click event callback. The `var` makes the variable local to that scope/closure.

```
 if (x === 1) {
      alert("test1");
      x = 2;
  }
  else if (x === 2) {
      alert("test2");
      x = 3;
  }
  else {
      alert("test 3");
  }
```

As a side point the very first `var` is not necessary, `var x = 1` and `x = 1` does the same thing when the code is not in a closure/function. All they are doing is assigning `window.x = 1`.

Comment: "closure" **is not** a synonym for (anonymous) functions in javascript. If you wanted to say "anonymous function" then you needed to say "anonymous function". "closure" term in your expression makes not much sense.

Comment: That is true, but functions do create a closures.

Comment: "That is true, but a function does create a closure" -- this doesn't make much sense either. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures "A closure is a special kind of object that combines two things: a function, and the environment in which that function was created"

Comment: Just to be more clear: as you pointed out - `var` defines a variable local to the current scope. That's it. `closures` are irrelevant here, because the main closure feature is that it handles variables from the outer scope, while we are talking about local scope.

Comment: thanks so much for the help, your explanation was clean and clear!